# Forgiveness Blasphemy of the Holy Spirit

Tags: sin, eternal-life, pneumatology

Here is a conundrum, If we take what Jesus said in the Bible I find there is a problem with this particular sin - Could it be that the early church added it to make a point about something else and unfortunately our generation ran with it.

> Matthew 6:14 For if you forgive men when they sin against you, your
>   heavenly Father will also forgive you.  But if you do not forgive men
>   their sins, your Father will not forgive your sins.
>
> Matthew 26:28 This is my blood of the covenant, which is poured out
>   for many for the forgiveness of sins.
>
> Matthew 7:21 “Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter
>   the kingdom of heaven, but the one who does the will of my Father who
>   is in heaven. On that day many will say to me, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not
>   prophesy in your name, and cast out demons in your name, and do many
>   mighty works in your name?’ And then will I declare to them, ‘I never
>   knew you; depart from me, you workers of lawlessness.’
>
> John 14:23 Jesus answered him, “If anyone loves me, he will keep my
>   word, and my Father will love him, and we will come to him and make
>   our home with him.
>
> John 5:24 Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever hears my word and
>   believes him who sent me has eternal life. He does not come into
>   judgment, but has passed from death to life.
>
> John 11:25 Jesus told her, "I am the resurrection and the life. Anyone
>   who believes in me will live, even after dying. Everyone who lives in
>   me and believes in me will never ever die. Do you believe this,
>   Martha?"

Versus this

> Matthew 12:31-32 31 And so I tell you, every kind of sin and slander
>   can be forgiven, but blasphemy against the Spirit will not be
>   forgiven. 32 Anyone who speaks a word against the Son of Man will be
>   forgiven, but anyone who speaks against the Holy Spirit will not be
>   forgiven, either in this age or in the age to come.

However
If we look closely - Jesus said every kind of sin and slander can be forgiven,  Then he said that one sin will not be forgiven - How can this be?!  You cannot say every sin and then say - except one!

Further if we look at the scriptures above Jesus explicitly says that those who believe in him will inherit eternal life!  How can this be - Surely he should have put a stipulation that Blasphemy can cause one to loose this eternal life!  Considering this sin is the Greatest of All and the Only one that can catch us out it is very odd that this was not elabourated on more!  Not even by his desciples!

Comment: This is easily resolved by understanding  that the blasphemy of the Holy Spirit can only be committed by someone who is rejecting Christ, which is the only way to obtain forgiveness. Everything is forgivable 'if you believe in Christ', if you reject Christ absolutely (calling his work by the Spirit's the devils) even under extra-ordinary convictions from the Holy Ghost, then of course it can't be forgiven. Answered here: [link](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9834/how-do-the-proponents-of-the-idea-that-salvation-once-received-cannot-be-lost-ex/9842#9842)

Comment: He isn't saying that all sin could be forgiven and then going back later and changing that. He is saying all sin can be forgiven except this one all at the same time, in the same teaching. Additionally, as @Mike said, this particular sin is understood to be rejecting Christ, and, as we know that rejecting Christ will surely not bring us into heaven, it stands to reason that such a sin is "unforgivable". How can you be forgiven of it if you don't rely on Christ for that forgiveness?

Answer (score 2):

To put these Scriptures in proper perspective. The first thing we have to do is to understand what Jesus meant by blaspheming.

According to Merriam Webster blaspheming is defined as:

BLASPHE'ME, v.t. [Gr. The first syllable is the same as in blame, blasme, denoting injury; L. loedo, loesus; The last syllable is the Gr.,to speak.]

1. To speak of the Supreme Being in terms of impious irreverence; to revile or speak reproachfully of God, or the Holy Spirit. 1 Ki 21. Mark 3.
2. To speak evil of; to utter abuse or calumny against; to speak reproachfully of.

BLASPHE'ME, v.i. To utter blasphemy.

He that shall blaspheme against the Holy Spirit shall not be forgiven. Mark 3.

1. To arrogate the prerogatives of God.

This man blasphemeth. Who can forgive sins but God? Math.9. Mark 2.

So let's break it down and see if we can determine exactly what blaspheme meant to Jesus and the circumstances under which it was used.

Starting with the definition of blaspheme we see that it has two parts. The first part is to blame to the point of injury, while the second part denotes speaking. We also note that it is both a transitive to transitive verb, and that in the instance in which Jesus stated that is in the intransitive form a of the verb.

So let's look at the situation and find out what the circumstances were when Jesus made this statement. This

> Matthew 12:22 through 24  Then was brought unto him one possessed with a devil, blind, and dumb: and he healed him, insomuch that the blind and dumb both spake and saw. And all the people were amazed, and said, Is not this the son of David? But when the Pharisees heard it, they said, This fellow doth not cast out devils, but by Beelzebub the prince of the devils.

We find here that Jesus had just cast out a devil from a dumb and blind man. They are attributing his ability to cast out the devil to being possessed by Satan.

> Matthew 12:25 through 27  And Jesus knew their thoughts, and said unto them, Every kingdom divided against itself is brought to desolation; and every city or house divided against itself shall not stand: And if Satan cast out Satan, he is divided against himself; how shall then his kingdom stand?   And if I by Beelzebub cast out devils, by whom do your children cast them out? therefore they shall be your judges.

Jesus having the ability to read their thoughts understood what they were saying was embedded deeper than just the surface. Then he says that they're not making sense, since it is Satan's desire to take people away from God why would he get rid of a devil which was doing exactly what he wanted. Finally he says if that's what I'm doing how can you expect that you and those following you could ever overcome Satan and take people to heaven?

> Matthew 12:30  He that is not with me is against me; and he that gathereth not with me scattereth abroad.

Jesus further says that if they're not helping him to get people saved what they are doing is aiding Satan. It appears then that what Jesus is doing is, he is warning him that they are very very close to condemning themselves before God by causing someone to not Believe. This becomes more clear when we consider the following Scriptures.

> Matthew 18:6 and 7 But whoso shall offend one of these little ones which believe in me, it were better for him that a millstone were hanged about his neck, and that he were drowned in the depth of the sea. Woe unto the world because of offences! for it must needs be that offences come; but woe to that man by whom the offence cometh!
>
> Matthew 18:10 and 11 Take heed that ye despise not one of these little ones; for I say unto you, That in heaven their angels do always behold the face of my Father which is in heaven. For the Son of man is come to save that which was lost.
>
> Luke 11:10  For every one that asketh receiveth; and he that seeketh findeth; and to him that knocketh it shall be opened.
>
> Luke 11:13  If ye then, being evil, know how to give good gifts unto your children: how much more shall your heavenly Father give the Holy Spirit to them that ask him?

Answer (score 2):

> [Catechism of the catholic Church, 1864](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c1a8.htm)
>
> *"Therefore I tell you, every sin and blasphemy will be forgiven men, but the blasphemy against the Spirit will not be forgiven."* [Mt
>   12:31; cf. Mk 3:29; Lk 12:10]. **There are no limits to the mercy of
>   God, but anyone who deliberately refuses to accept his mercy by
>   repenting, rejects the forgiveness of his sins and the salvation
>   offered by the Holy Spirit**. [cf. John Paul II, DeV 46]. Such
>   hardness of heart can lead to final impenitence and eternal loss.

---

**The Church teaches that that the *unforgivable* sins, the sins against the Holy Spirit, opposed to the Theological virtue of Hope, are despair and presumption** (which seem to come together as it appears that the one in the state often vacillates between presumption and  depair with no in-between state).

cf. [Hope, 2090-2092, Catechism of the Catholic Church](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s2c1a1.htm)

> 2090 When God reveals Himself and calls him, man cannot fully respond
>   to the divine love by his own powers. He must hope that God will give
>   him the capacity to love Him in return and to act in conformity with
>   the commandments of charity. Hope is the confident expectation of
>   divine blessing and the beatific vision of God; it is also the fear of
>   offending God's love and of incurring punishment.
>
> **2091 The first commandment is also concerned with sins against hope, namely, despair and presumption:**
>
> **By despair, man ceases to hope for his personal salvation from God, for help in attaining it or for the forgiveness of his sins**. Despair
>   is contrary to God's goodness, to his justice - for the Lord is
>   faithful to his promises - and to his mercy.
>
> 2092 There are two kinds of presumption. **Either man presumes upon
>   his own capacities**, (hoping to be able to save himself without help
>   from on high), **or he presumes upon God's almighty power or his
>   mercy** (hoping to obtain his forgiveness without conversion and glory
>   without merit).